How to change theme colors in vuetify3 dynamically?
In vue2 you were able to change theme colors like this:
// Light theme
this.$vuetify.theme.themes.light.primary = '#4caf50'

// Dark theme
this.$vuetify.theme.themes.dark.primary = '#4caf50'

https://v2.vuetifyjs.com/en/features/theme/#customizing
How to achieve this inside of vue3? I am looking / trying since 2 hours but nothing works. I can't find a way to access the vuetify instance and I also can't find a way to access the themes.
The use case is that a user is logging in, then his branding information is retrieved and then theme is set (that would be my other option, register a theme after the fact) / updated (primary and secondary color update).

This question is similar to: Vuetify 3 - How to change theme dynamically?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Hi, I think I already made it quite clear... In the example you provided you just change the theme that you previously set up. It does not explain how to change the color of an active theme dynamically

You can use the useTheme composable to change your theme :
<script setup>
import { useTheme } from 'vuetify'

const theme = useTheme()

// then in a function or a lifecycle hook do :

theme.themes.value.light.colors.primary = '#4caf50'

</script>

Online demo

Hey, thanks mate! I tried something similar, but somewhere I probably made a mistake. When I tried to access ".themes" I got the message that its read only, but in the exact way you call it, it works.
